# Attributes not displaying

Tags: android-studio

Hi i am currently new to android studio. When clicking on an element in the design view it wont display all the attributes, its only displaying what is shown in image one. How can i display whats shown in image 2?

**Whats showing (Image 1)**

[image]

**Expected (Image 2)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart.

If it doesn't work

2. Update your gradle version and use latest SDK Version

Thank you